# Basic Postgres: How do I insert a value into all rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, dml

Sorry for asking such a basic question (I'm sure it is a duplicate) but I have searched extensively and I can't work out how to do what I need. I'm probably just searching for the wrong keywords.

I have a database table with an empty column. I want to insert a value in that column for all rows.

My table looks like this:

```
 wkb_geometry | geometry(Polygon,4326) |
 id           | integer                |
 area         | real                   |
```

I want to insert the area of the `wkb_geometry` into the area column for all rows.

I know how to calculate and update an individual row as follows:

```
update inspire_parcel set area=(select st_area(wkb_geometry::geography) 
  from inspire_parcel where id=24045271) where id=24045271;
```

But how can I do this for all rows?

If it makes a difference, I have a LOT of rows - more than 20 million.

Comment: Why not keep it simple? Try: `update inspire_parcel set id = 24045271 where id = NULL;` If not set in NULL try, `update inspire_parcel set id = 24045271 where id = '';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not need for the select, just update the column with the result of the function and leave out the where clause to update all rows:

```
update inspire_parcel 
   set area = st_area(wkb_geometry::geography);
```

To avoid overriding existing value, just use an appropriate WHERE clause:

```
update inspire_parcel 
   set area = st_area(wkb_geometry::geography)
where area is null;
```

This is also the correct way if you just want to do it for a single row:

```
update inspire_parcel 
   set area = st_area(wkb_geometry::geography)
where id = 24045271;
```